# Export Malfunction & Error 13

Tags: export

I hope this post is more clarifying. I get the Error 13 when uploading to Sketchfab. Attached are my export settings for the model. This is a new issue for me, haven’t had any trouble in the past! THAeNKS for any help!

Original posts with other pics. [Export Malfunction, Can’t Upload to Sketchfab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287400/export-malfunction-can-t-upload-to-sketchfab)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of posting a duplicate question, you should update your original question at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/287400/export-malfunction-can-t-upload-to-sketchfab

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)